# Passing same SelectList with different SelectedValues to View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag, selectlist

I have a view with two drop-downs, weekend Day 1 and weekend Day 2. I am in edit mode and from action I am passing my select list like this:

```
var WeekList1 = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
{
     new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "Select Day" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Sunday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Monday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Tuesday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Wednesday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Thursday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "Friday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "7", Text = "Saturday" }
 }, "Value", "Text", model.weekendDay1);


var WeekList2 = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
{
     new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "Select Day" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Sunday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Monday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Tuesday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Wednesday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Thursday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "Friday" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "7", Text = "Saturday" }
 }, "Value", "Text", model.weekendDay2);

ViewBag.WeekEnd1 = WeekList1;
ViewBag.WeekEnd2 = WeekList2;
```

I am creating same list twice just to pass different selected values. Is there any way to create it only once and pass it with different selected values. I do not want to crate new database table for this one.

**Update:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("WeekEnd1", null,  htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Will first way select the value itself? Can you give solution in answers section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model:

```
public class CustomModel
{
     public string Week1 { get; set; }
     public string Week2 { get; set; }
     public SelectList Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     CustomModel model = new CustomModel();         
     model.Items = new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
                            {
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "", Text = "Select Day" },
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Sunday" },
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Monday" },
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Tuesday" },
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "4", Text = "Wednesday" },
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Thursday" },
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "6", Text = "Friday" },
                                 new SelectListItem { Value = "7", Text = "Saturday" }
                             }, "Value", "Text");
     return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Week1, Model.Items)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Week2, Model.Items)
     <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
}
```

For this approach in post method, you can get the values based on model property.